# google Lookup is giving wrong values

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

VLook up function

I have 2 columns - activity and dependency.
In row I want to get time required by dependency.

In the image - last column is expected output, and second last column is what I have got

```
=LOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$C$6,$C$2:$C$6)
```

[image]

[google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sniTu26KF78p7sNHyPRla3tHvFYGWxMmCzZqA-7p-0o/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

*As per [LOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570) documentation:*

```js
LOOKUP(search_key, search_range|search_result_array, [result_range])
```

- *The LOOKUP function **will only work** properly `if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted`. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other
  related functions if data is not sorted.*

*You may try:*

```js
=index(xlookup(B2:B,A2:A,C2:C,))
```

[image]